# TypeError: login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'

Tags: python, django

I upgraded my project from Django 1.11 to 2.2, made all the changes but came with new error that says login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'.It worked fine with the previous version of Django 1.11 (All the other urls are working, only the landing page gives the error). I couldn't find any references to this issue. Below is the error and urls and views for the issue.

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MyWebsite\landing\views.py", line 43, in landing_validation
    login_response = login(request, template_name='landing.html')
TypeError: login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'
[19/Apr/2019 16:20:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 71948
```

Landing\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from landing.views import landing_validation

app_name='landing'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', landing_validation, name='landing')
]
```

Landing\views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login 

def landing_validation(request):
  login_response = login(request, template_name='landing.html')

  return login_response
```

C:\Users\User\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth__init__.py

```
def login(request, user, backend=None):

    """
    Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
    have to reauthenticate on every request. Note that data set during
    the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.
    """
    session_auth_hash = ''
    if user is None:
        user = request.user
    if hasattr(user, 'get_session_auth_hash'):
        session_auth_hash = user.get_session_auth_hash()

    if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
        if _get_user_session_key(request) != user.pk or (
                session_auth_hash and
                not constant_time_compare(request.session.get(HASH_SESSION_KEY, ''), session_auth_hash)):
            # To avoid reusing another user's session, create a new, empty
            # session if the existing session corresponds to a different
            # authenticated user.
            request.session.flush()
    else:
        request.session.cycle_key()

    try:
        backend = backend or user.backend
    except AttributeError:
        backends = _get_backends(return_tuples=True)
        if len(backends) == 1:
            _, backend = backends[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                'You have multiple authentication backends configured and '
                'therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the '
                '`backend` attribute on the user.'
            )
    else:
        if not isinstance(backend, str):
            raise TypeError('backend must be a dotted import path string (got %r).' % backend)

    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
    request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = backend
    request.session[HASH_SESSION_KEY] = session_auth_hash
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        request.user = user
    rotate_token(request)
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no need to do a landing_validation view this line solved the issue.

```
url(r'^$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='landing.html'), name='landing')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `login` function that you're using is not actually a view. It's just a regular function which you can use to authenticate a user and set the session cookie, etc.

Read the docs for it's usage: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

---

Judging by your code, it appears you want to use [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView).

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

def landing_validation(request):
    login_response = LoginView.as_view()(request, template_name='landing.html')

    return login_response
```

Comment: This got me rid of the template_name issue but i ran into new issue now. TemplateDoesNotExist at /
registration/login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
registration/login.html

Comment: `No module named 'django.contrib.auth.views.auth_views'; 'django.contrib.auth.views' is not a package`

Comment: @User Thank you for pointing this out. It should be `from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView`. I've updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Django 2.2 app I fixed similar error by using `LoginView` instead of `login`.

File *users/urls.py*:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
# from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see that django.contrib.auth.login takes request, user, and an optional backend.  There is no template_name.  This hasn't changed recently, so I think you would get the same problem in 1.11, too.

It looks like you want a view function, but django.contrib.auth.login is not that.  It doesn't return a response.